# Recording command line input and output on linux with C

Tags: c, unix, shell, process

Basically I want to do a program almost like a keylogger.  The thing is that I as network admin sometimes I don't remember what I did to a machine on certain case, or same times I make howto's and tutorials for linux. I want to record what have i done.
So basically the idea of this program is:
you type the name of the program, (I call it rat for the moment)

```
$ rat
Welcome everything from now on will be recorded
recording $ ls
file1 file2 file3
recording $ quit
Bye bye
```

Everything you do will go out to an xml file. Something like this

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<rat>
 <command>
   <input>ls</input>
   <output>file1 file2 file3</output>
   <err><err>
 </command>
</rat>
```

i am doing some tests with `fp_in = popen( input, "w");`
and `system`, but first with popen i cant change directories and with "system i cant properly manage the input and output.

I was also checking if there is something I can do to bash like a plugin but haven't find any information.

At some points if feels like it I should create another shell (which is way beyond my current abilities) or fork bash sh.  But it should been that complicated right.
I am open to suggestion where to start.
I am rusty with C, so I am reading again a lot of basic stuff.

With the xml file, later i was thinking on making a program to store this data and/or editing this data so i can create tutials and howto.

I can think of many ways of expanding this up to using printscreen so all the stored images go to a file you can upload to a server (for the moment i am glad to store the data). It could be a usefull tool.

ps. I do know this can be use for evil things too.

Answer (score 6):

There already exists the [`script`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/script) command, which will record all input and output into the terminal, writing it into a transcript. I would recommend just using that, unless you have particular needs that it doesn't meet. Actually, the nicest version of `script` that I've seen has been the [NetBSD version](http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?script++NetBSD-current), so you may want to look into that if the Linux version doesn't meet your needs.

If you would like to write it yourself, instead of using `system`, I would recommend that you use [`fork`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/fork.html)/[`exec`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/exec.html) to create a single shell process, which you copy all input and output into. To get an idea of how this works, I'd recommend looking at the source code for [an existing version of `script`](http://cvsweb.netbsd.org/bsdweb.cgi/src/usr.bin/script/script.c?rev=1.19&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup&only_with_tag=MAIN).

Comment: script opens a psudo-terminal (the same as xterm, sshd, telnetd, ...) and then splices that to the terminal (possibly another psudo-terminal) that the user was already interacting with, and logs most everything that went on between the two terminals.

Comment: Script does a lot of things, it is nice.  It even logs the whitespaces and backspace. I dont think it can do the xml thing, but it is nice. It handles real time transaction thanks i think my question has been answered

Comment: This is unfortunately not true. Script seems to only record **output**. I'm in a situation where I want to debug why a program is outputting crap instead of what is being written on it so I need to record both input and output. I don't have a solution yet. update: NetBSD `script` you are linking to seems to have it, thanks and +1.

Answer (score 1):

<s>Most shells have a `script` built-in which will simply record the text in- and out- from the command line. Not quite what you're looking for...</s> To my surprise `script` is not a built in, which means it *is* a model for building what you want.

The `script` command does almost what you want: it simply records the text in- and out- from the command line.

If you make your prompt distinctive (so that you can reliably tell the difference between shell commands and everything else) you can post-process the output of `script` to achieve your goals. Alternately you can hack `script` to get it to emit the XML you're looking for.

Comment: It seems like the shell thing right.  I will have to investigate more, now i am thinking of hacking programs like midnight commander to understand how do they tackle this problem.  They do similar things moving around directories.

Comment: on a second look script does a lot of what i ask

Answer (score 0):

You can also try approaching this from a different angle.  Instead of using a regular shell, connect to the machine using ssh or telnet and run your commands that way.  Many ssh/telnet clients ([PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/), for instance) have an option to log all console input and output during the session.  You should be able to post-process this log to generate whatever type of logfile that you need.

Depending on your setup, you might not even have to use a second machine (you should be able to ssh into yourself).

Comment: `screen` can also do logging.